# Is Raspberry Pi 4 4GB faster when using Pny Elite Pro Gen 2 vs Gen 1?

Tags: usb

I try to speed up my Pi 4GB and going to buy tomorrow one of these:

Pny Elite USB 3.1 Gen 1 Portable SSD

```
https://www.pny.com/elite-usb-3-1-portable-ssd
```

Pny Pro Elite USB 3.1 Gen 2 Type-C Portable SSD

```
https://www.pny.com/pro-elite-type-c-pssd
```

Is it worth to spend more money for Gen 2 SSD or is there some bottle neck, so Raspberry cannot use all that extra speed of Gen 2?

Speed specs:

```
https://seekingtech.com/pny-elite-vs-pny-pro-elite/
```

Answer (score 3):

The Pi 4 has no USB3.1 Gen 2 support (it has only type A USB3 sockets, and Gen 2 requires type C sockets), so the "Pro" version will likely be only marginally faster than the "regular", and certainly not twice as fast.